# Does the prefix "On" in the name of the C# methods imply anything?

Tags: c#, events, methods, keyword

Can anyone help me with this confusion?  Is there a special  meaning associated with the methods that I see in C# examples, 3rd party software, specially the methods handling events, that start with the Prefix "On"?

In other words is this a Language convention? Recommendation ? or KeyWord?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's usually an event.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It's a method that fires an event.  By convention, an event itself isn't prefixed with "On".

Comment: It is important, there are many cases where it makes more sense to override the method instead of subscribing the event.  Particularly so when additional classes derive from yours.  The event handler is always the last piece of code that sees the event.  You may well want to do something *before* the event is raised.  Or not raise it at all.  Both require overriding the method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is *convention* that a method that exists to fire an event would be prefixed with "On", i.e. `OnSomeEvent`, when called, would fire the `SomeEvent` event.  There is no keyword or other language construct that would force the use of the "On" prefix; it's merely a convention.

Creating such a method is also usually used when you need to allow the event to be fired explicitly from outside the class definition (usually from inheriting classes, hence why these methods are usually `protected`).  If the class is designed such that the event is only ever fired from within the class that defines it, there usually won't be any "On" method, which is why you don't see one in many cases.

Comment: for completeness - this is also by *convention* the extension point for intercepting the event in subclasses, rather than subscribing to the event on the same instance - by this same convention it is *often* (but not always) `virtual` so that the derived type can `override` it.

Comment: @Senvy : In other words its the name of the Delegate Instance?  Or the EventHandler. Right ?

Comment: @user1298925 No, it would be the name of the event, not the delegate that represents it's type.  `public event Action WokenUp` would generally have an `OnWokenUp` method, not an `OnAction` method paired with it.

Comment: @Marc Gravell:  Thank you . Do u happen to know about any URL on what you added. I wold need more clarifications to understnad it.

Comment: @ Senvy :  Thanks, can you show me an example perhaps on internet or if you have one handy?

Comment: @ Senvy :  Thanks, can you show me an example perhaps on internet or if you have one handy? Oh so if you put it on a timeline , this is the order of their execution:  OnWorkenUp -> event is invoked based on some criteria -> Action is invoked.

Comment: The convention is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/#events

Answer (score 11):

As per comments:

> Thank you . Do u happen to know about any URL on what you added. I wold need more clarifications to understnad it.

This is just to explain that; as a full example of the general case, this is the *established convention* - not a rule - there is noting to enforce this - it is just a common pattern that a lot of code uses:

```
public class SomeBaseClassWithAnEvent
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

    protected virtual void OnSomeEvent()
    {
        var handler = SomeEvent;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void SomeOtherMethodThatHasSideEvents()
    {
        //...do stuff...
        OnSomeEvent();
        //...do more stuff...
    }
}

public class SomeSubclass : SomeBaseClassWithAnEvent
{
    protected override void OnSomeEvent()
    {
        // custom stuff here to do it before the event
        base.OnSomeEvent();
        // or here to do it after the event
    }
}
```

This pattern allows two things:

- the subclass can invoke the event by calling the `On...` method
- the subclass can intercept the event to add functionality by *overriding* the `On...` method

And if you want to see how ingrained this pattern is - just go into whatever framework you are using (winforms, wpf, asp.net, asp.net mvc, whatever else you can think of) and just type `override`, then scroll down to `On`:

[image]

(hint... that scroll bar goes for *quite a while* in the `On...` range)